# Is there any way to simply use google mediapipe framework in android studio for handtracking?

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow, face-detection

I want to implement Hand Tracking using "Google Mediapipe Framework" but It is very tough for me to go with given google references.

Mediapipe Github :- https://github.com/google/mediapipe

Installation Doc :-  https://mediapipe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#setting-up-android-studio-with-mediapipe

I have followed the provided steps but unable to run the media-pipe library.

It is throwing "No Bazel found in the directory(xxx/xxx/mediapipe)" while I have installed "Bazel Plugin" in android-studio.

So, can anyone please suggest me to solve this problem or any good reference for "HandTracking" in android.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the "Bazel Plugin" for android-studio, you also need to install the Bazel build system.  You can follow the instructions for "Install Bazel" at http://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/docs/install.md

Comment: It is very difficult for building the aar file. Have many issues when following the document.